# How to use login() to navigate to HomePage using nebular auth/login library?

Tags: angular, nebular

I newly created the Angular Project with the nebular library installed. I want to create 3 pages.(Login, Register, and Home). I have already created login and register page with the help of built-in NbLoginComponent and NbRegisterComponent respectively. Now I want to navigate to HomePage once I click on login button of NbLoginComponent (basically I want to use this login() to navigate to HomePage) after the user successfully logs in. So where do I need to achieve such functionality?

Right now I am not able to do anything like that it stays in the same page with the NbLoginComponent.

Similarly, for NbRegisterComponent, if I use `<nb-register></nb-register>`, once the user does successful registration, I want to navigate to login page ---> after successful login --> Home page.

So where do I need to achieve such functionality with nebular library?

I have already got the nebular/auth related pages like login, register, logout etc. (with latest Angular 7 and latest nebular library).

NbLoginComponent and NbRegisterComponent Code only

Expected : By using login() from NbLoginComponent need to navigate to Home Page after the successful login.And By using register() from NbRegisterComponent need to navigate to loginPage after the successful registration.

Actual : In both of above situations, it stays in the same Page(means once you click on login button after successful login it stays in same login page, similarly for register.).

Comment: Here is the new documentation on redirects https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/ee2b83fa347a681a7dfb83fc594bc467d39c4371/docs/articles/auth/redirect.md If it still keeps you on the same page - it might indicate that the login wasn't successful and there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **NbLoginComponent.js** as it is and designed your page in the decorate function then I suggest you to add following code in the login() method as follows--

```
NbLoginComponent.prototype.login = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this.errors = [];
    this.messages = [];
    this.submitted = true;

    this.service.authenticate(this.strategy, this.user).subscribe(function (result) {
        _this.submitted = false;
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            _this.messages = result.getMessages();
            _this.router.navigateByUrl("/homepageurl");
        }
        else { 
            _this.errors = result.getErrors();
        }
        _this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
};
```

You will be redirected to the homepage.
Similarly you can add

> _this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");

in RegisterComponent to redirect to the login page.